# Syncing Ubuntu Online Accounts with Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, lts, online-accounts

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and latest .deb of thunderbird.

Is there a way to sync the online accounts of Ubuntu (email, calendar, etc.) with Thunderbird?

The thunderbird asks me to add all my accounts. But earlier, it used to show all online accounts in Thunderbird by default.